# When I select render my domain is visible

Tags: error

for some reason the fluid domain stays visible during render but not is texture view, can someone help? thanks.

images:

[image: the render not working]
[image: the thing being invisible]

Comment: Have you enabled the domain Mesh option? And also under Cache > Type, click on Replay? If it still doesn't work please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: but if i click replay, i cant bake it

Comment: please share your file

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/61b84cef50654fc28fc2ed3f3d34a34f

Comment: I can't see any fluid inflow or geometry object, that's probably why the domain keeps its cube shape

Comment: can you fix it? if so then can you do it and send me it? thanks. if not then ill see what i can do

Comment: it's not clear what you want to do, if you want an object that acts like a water tap, just add a new object, Type > Flow, Flow Type > Liquid, Flow Behavior > Inflow, then under Cache > Type > click on Replay

Comment: i did that with cube.fluid and cube.001

Comment: please only keep the necessary (not the smoke objects) and share again so that I can try your latest version